# cannot connect to compose mongodb with kafka on spring boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm running a spring boot app that listens to IBM Message Hub Kafka and then stores into compose for mongoDB on IBM Cloud.

I'm getting an error related to SSL certificate when I run Kafka and Compose for MongoDB together.

I am using compose for mongodb certificate and with a valid trust store and key.

If I use embedded mongo in spring boot, then all is fine.

**Things I've setup so far:**

I set up my compose for mongodb URI in my application properties file
I passed in the trust store and the key password as VM arguments with running the java application.

**Error:**
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:518) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]

Answer (score 0):

make sure to pass in your trust store and password after your jar like this
java -jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=JKS_HERE -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=PASS_HERE target/jarfilehere.jar